# Java What will happen if we assigned two objects to the same variable

Tags: java

In java, lets say I have executed this code

```
ClassA classa = new ClassA();
classa = new ClassA();
```

What will happen to the old object? will it be deleted, or it will stick in memory?

Comment: The old object will become subject to Garbage Collection and could be removed from memory.

Comment: It will be eligible for garbage collector.

Comment: .... as long as it is not being referenced elsewhere or "reachable" from another thread.

Comment: A new reference to the same Class A is going to be created, and it is going to replace the reference that had been assigned to the variable classa

Comment: If classa is pointer to a memory location that holds instance of ClassA, is it not logical that new initialization will place the new object in the same memory location, i.e. the first object will be overwritten?

Comment: @contrapost *"the first object will be overwritten?"* No, the new object gets new memory allocated and the memory of the old object will be freed during the next garbage collector run.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle so the classa will point to a new memory location, won't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *classa* variable will point to the new object ClassA. The old ClassA object will be eligible for Garbage Collection. You can find this behaviour documented in this [garbage collector document](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html).